# Is size of smallest unit of data written to file on file stream in binary mode always 8 bits?

Tags: c++, file, char

As I mentioned above,
 
**1-)** Is size of smallest unit of data written to file on file stream in *binary mode* always `8` bits? If it writes to file whatever character is passed with the function `put()`, can we say that it is always `8` bits?

**2-)** If we add an `integer` to a variable of `char` type, does position in character set of the variable change as many as the `integer` added, regardless of how bits of variable of `char` type are represented in memory whichever platform/machine it is tried on? And what if we exceed the limit of value the variable can take in any system that has `signed` or `unsigned` `char` representation of `char` type? Does it always return from end to begining when adding and do the reverse for extracting?
**3-)** What exactly I want to know is whether there is a portable way to storage data in file for *binary mode* and how common file formats are manipulated by reading and writing without problems.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1) The C++ standard is pretty clear that a "byte" (or `char`) is not necessarily 8 bits, for one thing. Although machines with 9- or 12-bit `char` types are not very common, if you want extreme portability you need to take this into account in some way (e.g. specify that "our implementation expects a `char` to be 8 bits - which can of course be checked during compilation or runtime, e.g:

`#if (CHAR_BITS != 8)

        #error This implementation requires char_bits == 8.
 
     #endif`

or

```
if (CHAR_BITS != 8)
{
    cerr << "Sorry, can't run on this platform, CHAR_BITS is not 8\n";
    exit(2);
}
```

2) Adding an `int` value to a `char` value will convert it to an `int` - if you then convert it back to a `char`, it should be consistent, yes. Although behaviour is technically "undefined" for overflows between positive and negative values, which can cause strange things (e.g. traps for overflows) on some machines.

3) As long as it's clearly defined and documents, a binary format can be made to work well in a portable scenarion. See "JPG", "PNG" and to some degree "BMP" as examples where binary data is "quite portable". I'm not sure how well it works to display a JPG on a DEC-10 system with a 36-bit machine word tho'.

Comment: What I mean in 2) is: After guaranteeing number of bits of char type as 8, is there a certain solution to write value between 0 and 255 to file by using char type due to put() function taking char as parameter? Yes, this works on my machine but is it portable? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it should be perfectly portable.

Comment: Then how to specify 255th character of ASCII table? Is this suitable even for systems that char type is signed: file.put(255)?

Comment: And does read and write functions read and write in a form that value at adress of variable or array passed as parameter is represented as bits?

Comment: Technically, numbers above 127 are negative. However, if you also require that the machine behaves in a consistent way here, I don't really foresee that there will be any real problem, except for extremely exotic systems - are you looking to run this on IBM mainframes, Digital PDP-11 and DSP systems? If not, I think you're safe. Certainly works on 29k, Mips, ARM, x86, 68K, Sparc, VAX, PDP-11 and PowerPC (and probably lots of others that I can't think of now). And yes, read and write should do this.

Answer (score 2):

1) No, the smallest unit of allocation is a disk page, as defined by the filesystem parameters.  With most modern file systems, this is 4k, though some next-gen file systems exceptionally small files' content can be stored in the inode, so the content itself takes no extra space on the disk.  FAT and NTFS page sizes range from 4k to 64k depending on how the disk was formatted.

1a) "smallest read/write" unit is usually an 8-bit byte, though on some oddball systems use different byte sizes ([CDC cyber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_Cyber) comes to mind with a 12-bit byte).  I can't think of any modern systems that use anything other than an 8-bit byte.

2) adding an integer to a char will result in a size integer result. The compiler will implicitly promote the char to integer before the arithmetic.  This can then be downcast (by truncation, usually) to a char.

3) Yes and yes.  You have to thoroughly document the file formats, including endianness of words if you plan to be running on different CPU architectures (i.e. Intel is little-ended, motorola is big-ended, and some supercomputers are weirdly ended).  These different architectures will read and write words and dwords differently, and you may have to account for that in your reader code.

3a) This is fairly common (though now with XML and other self-defining semistructured formats perhaps less so), and so long as the documentation is complete, there are few issues in reading or writing these files.

Comment: I added that answer as (1a).  It's hard to tell the OP intent with such an odd question.

Comment: 1) Ok, as an allocation in disk it ranges from 4k to 64k but I ask the smallest unit of allocation of stream buffer.I don't know the details of disk processing as a novice but the data is probably passed byte by byte to the stream and after stream is filled, from stream to disk in a way that the data can be written in smallest unit of allocation according to current disk format.
<br>
2)Then what if we try something like this: char a=5; a++;  ?
<br>
3)If I want to make my own portable file format in binary mode, what kind of obstacles exactly I can encounter in C++? Thanks.

Comment: thanks for 1a) and the reason why I asked such a question is only portability issue.

Comment: 1) see answer (1a).  (2) char a=5; a++; // a==6.  In C++, all the world is a number (3) It's not so hard to read or write binary files. As you're a novice, just create a struct, and use [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) to write to file, and [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) to read it.  This is a naive way to start, but it should get you going until you can learn more about the specifics.

Comment: I already know that.The thing I couldn't solve is issue of portability.What I mean by "char a=5; a++" is for limits exceeded. char a=0; a--; Is this always counterpart of 255. character of ASCII table regardless of sign of char type for current system.Char can be negative for that system but when writing to file by put(--a) with a=0 can we get the result of 255 in binary although sign of a is negative for that system?

Comment: I have been dealing for this problem for 3 days.I asked a few questions here but still am not relax. I even writed code to adjust bits of char type or to understand how many bits is there.I even created my own stream to be able to write to the file always in bytes with 8 bits by calculating LCM of 8 and unknown number of bits of the variable of char type.
What do you suggest as solution?

Comment: The byte `0xff` is represented as 255 if you're not concerned about sign, or -1 if you do care about sign.  Generally speaking in binary one always deals with the byte(s) as a positive/unsigned number, even if when you interpret it later it's negative.

Comment: So to answer your question, I don't suggest a solution. The system is working the way it's supposed to -- `-1` when cast to a signed type, and `0xff` or `255` when directly interpreting the bits on disk.

Comment: If you didn't get bored with my unending questions: Then, Does put(255) always write 255 to file in all platforms accepting 8 bits as the smallest unit to send to the stream? According to what you said or what I understand from that, bit representation of any value of variable of signed and unsigned char are same but how they are interpreted are different when casting. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Do get,put,read and write functions interpret the data passed as parameter, the same as actual bits at the adress of the variable? Isn't that platform specific?Or because bit reperesentations of signed char and unsigned char are same, we can get the same result only with char type? Thanks in advance.

Comment: nope, these routines just copy bits into a memory address (pointer).  It's up to you, as a programmer, to make sure they're going to the CORRECT memory address.

Comment: `put()` operates on an int, so is usually a word, not a byte.  A word is generally 16 bits, but can be 32 or 64 depending on the platform.

Comment: Why not just write a small program and see what happens?

Comment: OK, then, I will write program samples to ask if it is portable later on.